# How can I stack rows that share any column value in common?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure the wording of the title is optimal, because the problem I have is a little tricky to explain. In code, I have a df that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
a = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E']
b = [3, 1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12]
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b]).T

df
```

Yields

```
    0   1
0   A   3
1   A   1
2   A   2
3   B   3
4   B  12
5   B   4
6   C   7
7   C   8
8   D   3
9   E  10
10  E  12
```

I'm aware of groupby methods to group by values in a column, but that's not exactly what I want. I kind of want to go a step past that, where any intersection in column 1 between groups of column 0 are grouped together. My wording is terrible (which is probably why I'm having trouble putting this into code), but here's basically what I want as output:

```
    0   1
0   A-B-D-E   3
1   A-B-D-E   1
2   A-B-D-E   2
3   A-B-D-E   3
4   A-B-D-E  12
5   A-B-D-E   4
6   C   7
7   C   8
8   A-B-D-E   3
9   A-B-D-E  10
10  A-B-D-E  12
```

Basically, A, B, and D all share the value 3 in column 1, so their labels get grouped together in column 0. Now, because B and E share value 12 in column 1, and B shares the value 3 in column 1 with A and D, E gets grouped in with A, B, and D as well. The only value in column 0 that remained independent is C, because it has no intersections with any other group.

In my head this ends up being a recursive loop, but I can't seem to figure out the exact logic. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that A, B, C, D are arbitrary representations of the values in 0. I don't need the name to be in any alphabetical order or anything.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future is experiencing the same thing, this works (it's probably not the best solution in the world, though):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
a = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E']
b = ['3', '1', '2', '3', '12', '4', '7', '8', '3', '10', '12']
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b]).T
df.columns = 'a', 'b'
df2 = df.copy()

def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i

bad = True
i =1
while bad:
    print("Round "+str(i))
    i = i+1
    len_checker = []
    for variant in list(set(df.a)):
        eGenes = list(set(df.loc[df.a==variant, 'b']))
        inter_variants = []
        for gene in eGenes:
            inter_variants.append(list(set(df.loc[df.b==gene, 'a'])))
        if type(inter_variants[0]) is not str:
           inter_variants = [x for x in flatten(inter_variants)]
        inter_variants = list(set(inter_variants))
        len_checker.append(inter_variants)
        if len(inter_variants) != 1:
            df2.loc[df2.a.isin(inter_variants),'a']='-'.join(inter_variants)
    good_checker = max([len(x) for x in len_checker])
    df['a'] = df2.a
    if good_checker == 1:
        bad=False

df.a = df.a.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(list(set(x.split('-')))))
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following creates the output you want, without recursions. I have not tested it with other constellations though (other order, more combinations etc.).

```
a = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E']
b = [3, 1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12]
df = list(zip(a, b))

print(df)


class Bucket:
    def __init__(self, keys, values):
        self.keys = set(keys)
        self.values = set(values)

    def contains_key(self, key):
        return key in self.keys

    def add_if_contained(self, key, value):
        if value in self.values:
            self.keys.add(key)
            return True
        elif key in self.keys:
            self.values.add(value)
            return True
        return False

    def merge(self, bucket):
        self.keys.update(bucket.keys)
        self.values.update(bucket.values)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.keys} :: {self.values}>'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


res = []
for tup in df:
    added = False
    if res:
        selected_bucket = None
        remove_idx = None
        for idx, bucket in enumerate(res):
            if not added:
                added = bucket.add_if_contained(tup[0], tup[1])
                selected_bucket = bucket
            elif bucket.contains_key(tup[0]):
                selected_bucket.merge(bucket)
                remove_idx = idx

        if remove_idx is not None:
            res.pop(remove_idx)

    if not added:
        res.append(Bucket({tup[0]}, {tup[1]}))

print(res)
```

Generates the following output:

```
$ python test.py 
[('A', 3), ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 12), ('B', 4), ('C', 7), ('C', 8), ('D', 3), ('E', 10), ('E', 12)]
[{'B', 'D', 'A', 'E'} :: {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 12}>, {'C'} :: {8, 7}>]
```